# Given a word pat and a text txt. Return the count of the occurrences of anagrams of the word in the text

Tags: arrays, sliding-window

Given a word pat and a text txt. Return the count of the occurrences of anagrams of the word in the text.

Example 1:

Input:
txt = forxxorfxdofr
pat = for
Output: 3
Explanation: for, orf and ofr appears
in the txt, hence answer is 3.

i tried using sliding window approach but didn't get the desired output! where am i wrong?

here's my code :

```cpp
int search(string pat, string txt)
{

    string s = "";
    int n = txt.size();
    int k = pat.size();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int count = 0;
    sort(pat.begin(), pat.end());
    while (j < n)
    {

        s += txt[j];


        if (j - i + 1 < k)
        {
            j++;
        }

        else if (j - i + 1 == k)
        {

            string temp = s;
            sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
            if (temp == pat)
            {
                count++;
            }
            // size_t index = i;
            s.erase(i, 1);

            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Do not post _pictures_ of _code_.  This site has markup for presentation of code.  We can't copy, paste, edit or compile a picture of code.

Comment: ok will keep that in mind also my apology!

Comment: Your picture was a complete program, the code is just the `search()`  function.  Anyone wishing to build and test it now has to do that work (and they may not).  Also you should indicate what result you _do_ get for that input.  Have you stepped this code in a debugger to see whether it does what intended?  Learning to debug your own code, and specifically using a source-level debugger will serve you better in the long run than having this corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stepping the code in a debugger shows that on the third iteration `s` is `"oxx"` not `"rxx"`. It then becomes clear that you need to erase the *first* character from `s` not the `i`<sup>th</sup>.

Change:

```cpp
    s.erase(i, 1);
```

to

```cpp
    s.erase(0, 1);
```

I have not tested with other input but for your example it return 3.

Note that you have somewhat over complicated the implementation (in my opinion).  The following is exactly your algorithm, but simpler and easier to understand code (again in my opinion).

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std ;

int search(string pat, string txt)
{
    size_t patlen = pat.size();
    int end = txt.size() - patlen ;
    int count = 0;

    sort(pat.begin(), pat.end());

    for( int i = 0; i <= end; i++ )
    {
        string subtxt = txt.substr( i, patlen ) ;
        sort(subtxt.begin(), subtxt.end());
        if( subtxt == pat)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

As a matter of style, efficiency and const-correctness, I'd recommend changing the interface to `search()` as follows:

```cpp
int search( const string& patr, const& string txt )
{
    string pat( patr ); // modifiable copy

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it passed all the test cases!!
i should have debugged it.

Comment: btw loved your solution!!

Comment: @Abhimanyu I would recommend `int search( string pat, const string& txt)`.  No need to create a copy of `txt` - pass by const reference.

Comment: yeah sure. Can you tell me the use case of it?

Comment: @Abhimanyu It is a matter of efficiency and "const correctness".  Passing a sting by copy requires construction if a new string object and associated memory allocation. As a matter of style and consistency, I'd make `pat` a const-reference too, and make a local copy before sorting.